# VS2010 linker error, looking for a .lib of a .dll file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, linker-errors, workspace

I am building a Visual C++ 6.0 workspace in Visual Studio 2010, so that it'll update some dependencies

I have all the files and dll's it is looking for, it builds but then fails at linking with this error

`1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '\Projects\exe\CRelease/api.lib'`

I have api.dll which it needs to build, but I don't have a .lib file version of it. and even if I did (like if I somehow converted the .dll into a .lib), I wouldn't know where to place it in a directory structure

how do I "fix" this?

guidance appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `api.dll` would have an accompanying import library called `api.lib` which is what you need to link to.  The import library is different to a statically-compiled version of `api` (which would also likely be called `api.lib`) - it's more like a list of available functions provided by the dll, and so will usually be much smaller than a corresponding static library.

If you do find or get `api.lib`, it doesn't really matter where it lives, as long as it can be accessed by your linker.

If you don't find the import library, you're looking at doing explicit run-time linking where `api.dll` is loaded and unloaded explicitly in your code, and `api`'s exported functions are called through function pointers.

Comment: Either provide the full path to `API.lib` in `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` or provide the full path to `CRelease` in `Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` and just have `API.lib` (not `\Projects\exe\CRelease/API.lib`) in `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.